# Timer inside foreground service is not accurate?

Tags: android

I'm using timer inside a foreground service and get inaccurate activations.

When the phone is connected to the USB (awake) then the samples are ok, but when the phone is not connected to the USB, the timer expires at strange intervals.

Any idea why?

Comment: user733284 it would help if you could post the code that you are using. Just edit your question and add the code that creates the timer

Answer (score 0):

> but when the phone is not connected to the USB, the timer expires at strange intervals.

The device is probably falling asleep. You should seriously consider switching away from `Timer` to using `AlarmManager`, as it will:

- Allow you to get control even if the device is asleep
- Allow you to get rid of the always-running foreground service (just process each alarm event as it occurs with a [`WakefulIntentService`](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-wakeful))